# The neutrality condition and the (non)-vanishing of the one-point correlator for the bosonic vertex operator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Consider the massless scalar field Hamiltonian,
\begin{align}
H = \frac{1}{2}\int \Pi^2- (\partial_x\phi)^2 dx
\end{align}
with $\Pi \sim \partial_t\phi$ the conjugate field of $\phi$. This Hamiltonian is treated in a number of texts, in particular [Shankar's text on Bosonization](http://th-www.if.uj.edu.pl/~acta/vol26/pdf/v26p1835.pdf) on page 1841 and [the Conformal Field Theory book by Di Francesco, Mathieu and Sénéchal](http://books.google.ie/books?id=keUrdME5rhIC&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl#v=onepage&q&f=false) (chapter 6 and 9). Furthermore, my question also relates to [this text by Von Delft and Schoeller](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9805275) on bosonization.

Shankar defines the vertex operator as the normal ordered operator $:e^{i\alpha\phi}:$. He states (p1843) that the one-point correlator is unity, $\langle :e^{i\alpha\phi}:\rangle =1$, since the exponential can be expanded and only the first term does not vanish.

But just before that he also states that the two-point correlator
$$
\langle :e^{i\alpha\phi}: :e^{i\beta\phi}: \rangle 
$$
vanishes *unless* $\alpha + \beta = 0$. This is the neutrality condition and it follows from the fact that $\phi\rightarrow \phi + a$ is a symmetry of the Hamiltonian, which needs to be respected by the (two-point) correlators. That sounds convincing enough, but then **why does the one-point correlator not vanish according to that same argument**?

To add to (my) confusion the normal ordered form is given by
$$
:e^{i\alpha\phi}:  = e^{i\alpha\phi_+}e^{i\alpha\phi_-}
$$
where $\phi_{\pm}$ contain all creation/annihilation operators. So using some rules of exponentiated operators (see appendix C of Von Delft) one can reorder the operators such that
$$
:e^{i\alpha\phi(z_1)}: :e^{i\beta\phi(w_1)}: = f(z-w) :e^{i(\alpha+\beta)\phi(w_1)}:  + \cdots
$$
with $f(z-w)$ a (singular) c-number. This is of course just the OPE. But that would imply that if the right hand side has a non-vanishing correlator, then the left hand side is non-vanishing as well. **If the one-point correlator does not vanish, why does the two-point correlator need to obey the neutrality condition?**

Di Francesco has some other, more elaborate proofs using Ward identities (Chapter 9) that show that indeed $\alpha+\beta = 0$ in order for the correlator to be non-zero. In particular that means that, according to their conventions, any $N$-point correlator vanishes unless the neutrality condition is satisfied. It could be that the different texts have different conventions that I'm missing and everything is fine. Still, a different question arises: **If the exponentials in the normal ordered operators are expanded, and only the first (unit) term is kept, then surely the one-point correlator is just $1$**? Why does this approach fail, according to their conventions?

Let me also mention Von Delft and Schoeller. They also state that the one point correlator of the normal ordered operator $:e^{i\alpha\phi}:$ does *not* vanish. Instead they define the vertex operator (chapter 9) as
$$
V_\alpha = \left(\frac{L}{2\pi}\right)^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}}:e^{i\alpha\phi}: 
$$
with $L$ the system size (periodic boundary conditions). They state that "evidently $\langle V_\alpha\rangle =\delta_{alpha,0} $ in the limit of $L\rightarrow\infty$.". **Does the neutrality condition then only hold in the $L\rightarrow\infty$ limit?**. This would invalidate Di Fransesco's treatment, I presume.

So, in short, I'm quite confused on how to "merge" these different treatments.

Comment: DiFransesco's treatment is incorrect, the correct answer is Von Delft's and Schoeller, but the reason is the infrared problem with a single scalar, and it probably makes no serious problem for the rest of the book. You should always think of the scalar in path-integral in imaginary time, where the answers to these things are obvious, and the normal ordering is just obvious subtractions of propagators between the same vertex.

Comment: @RonMaimon this seems like an answer, why post in the comments?

Comment: @tmac: Because I didn't check it in detail, nor did I work it out enough to give a detailed explanation (also, I could be wrong about Von-Delft and Schoeller, it just "feels" right because it has to have a dependence on the boundaries, but maybe they screwed up a factor somewhere, I didn't check yet. Also, I need to work things out with normal ordered operator formalism just to check, I don't use this often). I just wanted to give a quick heads up to the OP in case he needs a quick answer, and a longer answer when I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for your comment. I think you are correct -- Di Fransesco is probably too "sloppy", and the neutrality condition only holds in the $L\rightarrow\infty$ limit, provided the vertex operators are properly normalized. The normal ordered exponential $:e^{i\alpha\ph}:$ without normalization should have a unit vacuum expectation value.

Comment: I think the same question is asked here, and the answer seems to be correct and complete https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462925/correlator-of-a-single-vertex-operator

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all it must be clearly stated the composite operators of which quantum field
theory you consider.  I can offer you one setup in which everything is perfectly clear: the
compactified free boson living on the   cylindrical world-sheet (= toroidal compactification of the closed string).  It then has to be said what is meant by normal ordering:  for me it will mean putting the annihilation operators of the oscillatory string modes right to the creation operators **but not ordering the zero modes** (i.e. the  position and the momentum of the string). Now the vanishing or non vanishing of   correlators like $\langle :e^{i\alpha\phi}: :e^{i\beta\phi}: \rangle$ or  $\langle :e^{i\alpha\phi}:  \rangle$ can be seen just by performing
calculations in the zero mode sector and the  result is compatible with the neutrality condition: the 2-point correlator vanishes unless $\alpha+\beta=0$ and 1-point correlator vanishes unless $\alpha=0$. How does it come about? Well, the Hilbert space of the theory
$H$ is the tensor product $L^2(S^1)\otimes F_L\otimes F_R$ (I am ignoring the winding zero mode sector for simplicity), where $S^1$ is the target circle on which the string is compactified and  $F_{L,R}$ are the Fock spaces for the left and right movers, respectively. In particular, the vacuum $\vert 0\rangle\in H$ can be written as the direct product $\vert 0\rangle_0\otimes \vert 0\rangle_L\otimes \vert 0\rangle_R$, where $\vert 0\rangle_0$ stands for  the normalized constant function in $L^2(S^1)$ and  $\vert 0\rangle_{L,R}$ are the Fock vacua. The vertex operator  $V(\alpha)=:e^{i\alpha\phi}:$ has now the  structure $V(\alpha)=e^{i\alpha\phi_0+i\alpha pt}: e^{i\alpha\hat\phi}:$ where the $\hat\phi$ is the oscillator part of the field $\phi$.  Let us now calculate
$$\langle :e^{i\alpha\phi}:  \rangle= \ _0\langle 0\vert e^{i\alpha\phi_0+i\alpha pt}\vert 0\rangle_0 \ _L\langle 0\vert\otimes\ _R\langle 0\vert  : e^{i\alpha\hat\phi}:\vert 0\rangle_R\otimes \vert 0\rangle_L=  \ _0\langle 0\vert e^{i\alpha\phi_0 +i\alpha pt }\vert 0\rangle_0 
=$$ $$=e^{\frac{i\alpha^2t}{2}}\int_{S^1}e^{i\alpha\phi_0}d\phi_0 = \delta_{\alpha,0}.$$
The calculation of $\langle :e^{i\alpha\phi}: :e^{i\beta\phi}: \rangle$ is slightly more involved but the result is indeed proportional to $\delta_{\alpha+\beta,0}$ because of the contribution from the zero mode sector.